# Is there any difference in the battery consumption when my background is black and when it is white?

Tags: battery, display, nokia-lumia-630

I know that the battery must hold longer when my background is black, but is the difference worth changing the background color?

My phone is a Nokia Lumia 630 with Windows Phone 8.1 and the display [specs](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_lumia_630-6232.php) are:

- Type: IPS LCD capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
- Size 480 x 854 pixels, 4.5 inches (~221 ppi pixel density)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That actually depends on the type of display you have, and hence on the exact model of your phone.

[**AMOLED**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMOLED) displays light up each pixel individually, with the amount of energy required per pixel depending on the brightness of the colour that the pixel is displaying. A fully white pixel will consume more energy than any other colour, and black pixels consume no energy at all.

By contrast, [**LCD**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display) displays use a separate backlight (typically LEDs, although in the past CCFL tubes were also used in larger displays), which is run at the same brightness regardless of what's displayed on the screen.

Consequently, while an AMOLED display will benefit from having a dark background, an LCD display will not. Since your Lumia 630 has an LCD display, the answer for you is **no**, changing the background colour will have no appreciable effect on battery life.

A recent article at AAWP titled [Why LCD is now a better choice than AMOLED for smartphones](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/20206_Why_LCD_is_now_a_better_choice.php) touches on this subject as well, so give it a read if you want to know more.

To find out which type of display your phone has, go to the [Microsoft Mobile website](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile), find your phone and read its specifications.